# Move diagonally in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have my maze and can go north east south west but how do i move ne or sw.
if possible can you guys give me examples using my code. thanks its a 4x4 array.

the user interface

```
    //Begin user dialog
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    input ="";
    while(!input.equals("quit"))
    {
       System.out.println(map.rooms[row][col].name);
       System.out.print(">");
       input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        switch (input) {
            case "n":
                if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("n"))
                    row--;
                else
                    System.out.println("You cant go that way");
                break;
            case "s":
                 if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("s"))
                    row++;
                else
                    System.out.println("You cant go that way");
                 break;
            case "w":
                if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("w"))
                    col--;
                else
                    System.out.println("You cant go that way");
                break;
            case "e":
                if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("e"))
                    col++;
                else
                    System.out.println("You cant go that way");
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to char-parse your input

```
while(!input.equals("quit"))
{
   System.out.println(map.rooms[row][col].name);
   System.out.print(">");
   input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
   char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

   for(char c : inputArray){

    switch (input) {
        case "n":
            if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("n"))
                row--;
            else
                System.out.println("You cant go that way");
            break;
        case "s":
             if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("s"))
                row++;
            else
                System.out.println("You cant go that way");
             break;
        case "w":
            if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("w"))
                col--;
            else
                System.out.println("You cant go that way");
            break;
        case "e":
            if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("e"))
                col++;
            else
                System.out.println("You cant go that way");
            break;
```

Comment: sorry new to java what is char-parse. gonna go look it up but a simple answer helps too.

Comment: it could not be more simpler, I just added two lines to your code :P

Comment: but what does it mean and do is my question? from looking it up its converting a String to char. I appreciate you giving me the line of code, but i wanna understand and learn as im doing this :). like i put the char in my code now what?

Comment: it converts the string to a char array and then, with the help of the for loop, you do the switch case for every letter that your array contains. so you have not to add cases. for example: if you type in: "seen"   this code would go one south, two times east and one time north.

Comment: ah I seen wow that's a useful tool. thanks pedrito and kai. my only thing is this is my project and we haven't really covered char so not sure if he will expect this. either way thanks ill keep looking around and doing trail n error

Comment: the char "seen" would move me go one south, two times east and one time north but i need the array to go from [0][0] to [1][1]. unless the char does that i think i haven't wrapped my mind around it.

Comment: if you would move from [0][0] to [1][1] the user have to input the string: "se".

Comment: "seen" was only an example of me to show that you can input a string which length is unlimited and the code will move for every char in this string which equals s,w,e or n.

Answer (score 0):

example north-east:

```
    case "ne":
        if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("ne")) {
            col++;
            row--;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You cant go that way");
        }
        break;
```

Comment: You need braces after if: case "ne":
        if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("ne")) **{**
            col++;
            row--;
        **}** else
            System.out.println("You cant go that way");
        break;